# component filtering - administrative_area not found in spanish

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

When the user opens the app, i make a google reverse geocoding request with the language set to spanish or 'es'.
For that request i get:

> "address_components" : [
>               {
>                  "long_name" : "Región Metropolitana de Santiago de Chile",
>                  "short_name" : "Región Metropolitana de Santiago de Chile",
>                  "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
>               },
>               {
>                  "long_name" : "Chile",
>                  "short_name" : "CL",
>                  "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
>               }
>            ]

The administrative_area_level_1 has the value of "Región Metropolitana de Santiago de Chile".
When i make an geolocation request in spanish and i use the value from the administrative_area_level_1 i received in the reverse-geolocation request in the component filtering on the administrative_area filter, for the exact same address, i get not valid response.
If i do the same procedure with the language set to english, i have no problems what so ever.
I've also found out that instead of using "Región Metropolitana de Santiago de Chile" for the geolocation request in spanish, i use ""Región Metropolitana de Santiago", the response is valid.

This problem started happening to our users this week.

I left you here some geolocation requests examples that show the issue:

**English**:
[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Moneda%20943&bounds=-33.441892%2C-71.194134%7C-33.441892%2C-70.106525&components=administrative_area%3ASantiago%20Metropolitan%20Region%7Ccountry%3ACL&sensor=true&language=en](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Moneda%20943&bounds=-33.441892,-71.194134%7C-33.441892,-70.106525&components=administrative_area%3aSantiago%20Metropolitan%20Region%7Ccountry%3aCL&sensor=true&language=en)

**Spanish using "Región Metropolitana de Santiago de Chile" that comes from the reverse-geolocation request**:
[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Moneda%20943&bounds=-33.441892,-71.194134%7C-33.441892,-70.106525&components=administrative_area:Regi%C3%B3n%20Metropolitana%20de%20Santiago%20de%20Chile%7Ccountry:CL&sensor=true&language=es](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Moneda%20943&bounds=-33.441892,-71.194134%7C-33.441892,-70.106525&components=administrative_area%3aRegi%C3%B3n%20Metropolitana%20de%20Santiago%20de%20Chile%7Ccountry%3aCL&sensor=true&language=es)

**Spanish using "Región Metropolitana de Santiago" instead of "Región Metropolitana de Santiago de Chile" that comes from the reverse-geolocation request**:
address=Moneda%20943&bounds=-33.441892,-71.194134%7C-33.441892,-70.106525&components=administrative_area:Región%20Metropolitana%20de%20Santiago%7Ccountry:CL&sensor=true&language=es